# How do I simplify this with a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am trying to simply this with a loop. The only thing that is changing in each block is the _1, _2, _3 (etc.). Basically, I want to listen to a bunch of (unique) 2-option radio sets for a change and do things accordingly.

```
    $( "input[name='radioset_1'" ).change(function() {
        if ($( "#option_A_1").prop( "checked" )) {
        // do option A thing for radioset_1
        } else {
        // do option B thing for rasioset_1
    });

     $( "input[name='radioset_2'" ).change(function() {
        if ($( "#option_A_2").prop( "checked" )) {
        // do option A thing for radioset_2
        } else {
        // do option B thing for rasioset_2
    });

     $( "input[name='radioset_3'" ).change(function() {
        if ($( "#option_A_3").prop( "checked" )) {
        // do option A thing for radioset_3
        } else {
        // do option B thing for rasioset_3
    });

     $( "input[name='radioset_4'" ).change(function() {
        if ($( "#option_A_4").prop( "checked" )) {
        // do option A thing for radioset_4
        } else {
        // do option B thing for rasioset_4
    });
```

Comment: Please release this. I've reworded it. Thanks, kirkbross

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to loop

```
var blocks_count = 4; // or how many blocks do you have
for(var i = 1; i <= blocks_count; ++i){
    $( "input[name='radioset_" + i + "'" ).change(function() {
        if ($( "#option_A_" + i).prop( "checked" )) {
        // do option A thing for radioset_i
        } else {
        // do option B thing for rasioset_i
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
    $( "input[type=radio]").change(function(e) {
        var str = ($(this).attr("name"));
        var arr = str.split("_");
        if ($( "#option_A_" + arr[1] ).prop( "checked" )) {
            // do option A thing for this radio   
        } else {
            // do option A thing for this radio
        };
    });
```

Comment: Your jQuery selector is wrong - `$( "input[type=radio]")` .
What if I have something like this along with other radio inputs - `<input type="radio" name="somethingelse_1" />` .